# How does Wordpress deal with / compile SASS?

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

Really simple answer possible but I've not had the chance to work with SASS yet and especially not in Wordpress so bear with me.

I'm working on a site that has been developed in Wordpress and need to make some edits to the CSS (just increase an element's min-height from 54px to 64px at the moment). It has been done using SASS and folders have been set up for the partials and imported via a main.scss.

Where I've got stuck is that I don't understand what I need to change or action to make the _general.scss file (imported via main.scss and in a folder) compile to update the style for this element. I've changed the value from 54px to 64px as it has saved in the _general.scss but this isn't reflected via the browser (if you view the actual scss page) hence it doesn't update the style.

I know I need to recompile it some how ...but how?

Sorry in advance for what is a newbie question from an experienced coder! (embarrassing!)

Comment: please provide the details of the website or template that you are using so we can see the code and how SASS is being handled.

Comment: hi ViCky - what would you need to see? I've found a bunch of random file that display command line stuff such as: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/engine.rb:721:in `parse_property'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/engine.rb:681:in `parse_property_or_rule'.... would this point to a specific type of compiling being used? I guess what I'm asking in my question is where can I start to look (where would it normally / could be) to find out how it would / could be complied?

Comment: please go through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not necessarily need to edit the CSS of the template. You always have other options at your disposal.

- you can either create a child theme and make changes in it
- you can also create a custom style sheet and import the main stylesheet in your style sheet and put your code into your stylesheet
- or you can simply download a plugin which will allow you to put your custom css in the backend of wordpress and the plugin will import the custom css in the end of the main css file.

Following is a link to a plugin that will give you a window to add your custom css into:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Please use this and do not get messed up with SASS.

Comment: Thanks viCky - sometimes the most obvious answer is staring right at you. I'll do this and learn SASS some other time! Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Dan simple custom css allows to only add css to whole website. Will be better to use
http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/ OR  http://wordpress.org/plugins/css-injector/